# UI-Router How to automatically load a nested view within the parent view as a default

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been playing with UI-Router since ngRoute doesn't quite cover what I needed based on my different layouts requiring multiple nested views.  What I can't figure out in UI-Router is how to load default nested views without having to click a link.  I created a crude example of what I'm mean in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DO2CgdCnH6k0bnLQCtx0?p=preview)

Essentially there are two main route within each there is a container which hosts nested views.  I want to load a default view into them without have to click a ui-sref.

```
<h1>Auth Panel</h1> <-- main route 1
Just a container for login/forgot/reset
<hr/>
<a ui-sref="auth.login">Show Login</a><br> <-- can click to load nested view, but want to autoload
How to show automatically /login within the panel <br>
without having to click show login?
<div ui-view></div> <-- child to autoload with /login
```

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 12):

On your parent state add a param

```
.state('parentState', {
//...
    params: {
        autoActivateChild: 'parentState.childState'
    }
//...
})
```

And add this somewhere

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState){
    var aac;
    if(aac = toState && toState.params && toState.params.autoActivateChild){
        $state.go(aac);
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is $state defined?

Comment: Fantastic solution.  Clean.

Comment: HappyCoder, it needs to be injected wherever you have the event handler (second code chunk). Probably in the module definition

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to navigate automatically to a default child state when the parent loads, you could trigger a click on that particular `ui-sref` in your controller.

```
angular.element("#childElementId").trigger('click');
```

Comment: Please don't throw people off the angular path... Learn the tool before you give any advice.